# Why is this Powershell Script pulling unexpected files for ipv4 search?

Tags: powershell, ipv4

I constructed a power shell script to find config files that contain an ipv4 address. However, the script is returning files that do not have an ip address. The below script is returning the file info below:

One of the returned files: *"C:\SoftwareDevelopment\SourceCode\subversion\branches\SACB_Sprint1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\content\App.config.transform"*

Below are the contents of that file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Below is the PowerShell script:

```
$Path = "C:\SoftwareDevelopment\SourceCode\subversion\branches\"
$Text = "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\temp\IPV4SearchResults.txt"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.config*" -recurse > $Results
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
  ForEach-Object { 
     If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
        $PathArray += $_.FullName
        $PathArray += $_.FullName
     }
  }
```

Comment: When I create a file with that content, it doesn't match that regex. (But then, how is that regex going to match an IPv4 address when it has a space in the middle?)

Comment: Thank You. I removed the space but it didn't solve the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Brian the space was incorrect, but would not have been causing the issue. I also am not able to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your script slightly. I tested it with 2 files, one with the sample code from the matched file you posted and the second with the same code as well as an IPv4 address thrown in and only the one with the IPv4 address matched.

Give this a go:

```
$Path = "C:\SoftwareDevelopment\SourceCode\subversion\branches\"
$Text = "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\temp\IPV4SearchResults.txt"

$foundfiles = Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.config*" -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} 

$foundfiles | % { 
     If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
        $PathArray += $_.FullName
     }
 }
$Patharray > $results
```

Comment: I like the changes but the query is still pulling that file. I made sure to delete the file and run the script again. I also have validated the contents of that file again.

Comment: It's not matching for me.  Not sure what's different on your end.

Comment: I see what's happening. I'm looking at the file output itself,  you must be looking at the screen output. $foundfiles > $results is writing all files matching the filter to the file and then you're filtering by the regexpression after. I commented out $foundfiles > $results and changed $Patharray at the end to $Patharray > $results and that worked. If you change your code I'll check your response as the answer.

Comment: Yes, didn't realize what you were looking at.  Got it and I edited answer accordingly.